# Scrape urls from dynamic webpage using Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to make a web scraper in Scrapy that extracts 10000 links of news from this website https://hamariweb.com/news/newscategory.aspx?cat=7
This webpage is dynamic when I scroll down more links load.

I tried it with selenium but it's not working.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class WebnewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'webnews'
   allowed_domains = ['www.hamariweb.com']
   start_urls = ['https://hamariweb.com/news/newscategory.aspx?cat=7']


 def __init__ (self):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
   # options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito') 
    self.driver = webdriver. Chrome("C://Users//hammad//Downloads//chrome 
    driver",chrome_options=options)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    pause_time = 1
    last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    #start = datetime.datetime.now()

    while True:
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 400);")
        time.sleep(pause_time)
        print("\n\n\nend\n\n\n")
        new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

The above mentioned code opens a browser in incognito mode and continues to scroll down.  I also want to extract 10000 news links and want to stop the browser when limit reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add logic for gathering URLs to your parse() method by gathering the css hrefs:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    pause_time = 1
    last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    #start = datetime.datetime.now()
    urls = []
    while True:
        if len(urls) <= 10000:
            for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
                urls.append(href) # Follow tutorial to learn how to use the href object as you need
        else:
            break # Exit your while True statement when 10,000 links have been collected
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 400);")
        time.sleep(pause_time)
        print("\n\n\nend\n\n\n")
        new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

There's a lot of information regarding how to handle links in the scrapy tutorial  [following links section](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links). You can use the information there to learn what else you can do with links in scrapy.

I haven't tested this with the infinite scroll, so you may need to make some changes, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply solved it :).... but data not export to csv, csv file is always blank :(

Comment: What are you using to write the file to csv? Have you checked the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for writing to csv?

Comment: Cool -- can you upvote and accept the answer please?